# Inside a <section> element; if <header> is used, is <footer> a requirement, or not?

Tags: html

Here is my code, at the moment:

```
<section id="one">
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>
<section id="two">
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>
<section id="three">
    <h2>Section Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>
```

I was contemplating using the `<header>` element to surround each section's `<h2>`, but would I then also have to use a `<footer>` element at the bottom of each section, as well? I have a feeling that the `<footer>` element of each section would more often than not be empty, unless footnotes were necessary, such as a source of information, or notes about the information provided in a paragraph, etc.

Is this part of the specification's rules, or am I purely basing this on the assumption that "if you have one, you should have the other"?

Comment: It's not necessary to add a footer-tag.

Comment: Wrapping single headlines into `header` elements won’t add much semantically either …

Comment: @CBroe - If it's not going to help, I don't think I'll bother with it.

Comment: Also, if you do use a footer, it doesn't have to be at the bottom. The footer element is for containing metadata about the section - i.e. information that typically goes at the bottom - but it's a semantic, not a styling, container so you can place it where you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not have to use both a `header` and a `footer` if you use one. They are similar, but completely independent. The HTML5 specification adds no such restrictions.

> Content model: Flow content, but with no header, footer, or main element descendants.
>
> The header element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A header typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids.
>
> – [`<header>` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element)

> Content model: Flow content, but with no header, footer, or main element descendants.
>
> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like.
>
> When the footer element contains entire sections, they represent appendices, indexes, long colophons, verbose license agreements, and other such content.
>
> – [`<footer>` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element)

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to use both of them.

It's ok to use:

- both of them
- none of them
- only header
- only footer

It's similar to **Microsoft Word**. You can create a document that has only the title as header, only the page number as footer, both of them or none of them.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags are only used to describe your content, you don't have to use any of `header/footer` tags or you can use one of them, or both together, it's really up to you.

Edit:
Also you can use them multiple times in a single html file

Comment: I guess you *can* use them multiple times, but I can't think of a situation where is want to. Can you?